# Finding Vector3 with ray and range

Tags: vector, xna, distance, raytracing

im hoping you can help me with this problem.

I have 2 Positions: Pos1 and Pos2

They both have a "range" in which they can attack eachother, and i need to tell my AI to move them within range of eachother before attacking.

So i want to find the Vector3 point on Pos2's range circle that is the closest to Pos1.

Basically that would be,   the x,y,z + radius (range) and then finding the point on the output circle where the ray between Pos1 and Pos2 touch the circle..

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Vector3 pointOnPos2RangeCircle = Pos2 + (Vector3.Normalize(Pos1 - Pos2) * radiusOfPos2RangeCircle);
```

Comment: nice, ill try this, looks logical enough.. Thanks

Comment: This opens up a new frontier in my Developement, where positioning things relative to eachother and such is possible.. thanks for the very accurate and helpfull answer .. +1